# Change Time Picker Selection to every 15mins

Tags: javascript, jquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPyI1.png)

I want to change the minutes difference from 5minutes to 15 minutes, so it should be like 00 15 30 instead of 00 05 10
Pls see the image.. using js .timepicker for it

```
 $(time_input).timepicker
  showCloseButton: true
  showPeriod: true
  showleadingZero: false
```

given like below.. the default time picker

[enter link description here](https://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/)

Comment: at least give link to this timepicker

Comment: Looks like jQuery UI? If so when you initialize it add interval: 15 to the function.

Comment: Maybe a quick review of [ask]

Comment: It looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPyI1.png

Comment: @RickCalder interval is not working.. any other solution ?

Comment: @bilal Check my answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(time_input).timepicker({
  showCloseButton: true,
  minutes: {    
   interval: 15              // Interval of displayed minutes
  },
  showPeriod: true,
  showleadingZero: false
});
```